# Error while posting answer

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've been trying to submit an answer or comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883836/read-actionscript-3-constants-from-swf-in-php) but get redirected [here](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/7883836/answer/submit).

I posted this because the error page suggests that I should do so. Is this common or something current & temporary?

I've taken a screenshot of my answer because I was just going to post the URL to it as a comment until the issue was resolved:

[image]

I'm using Google Chrome (and have been on every visit to the site thus far).

Comment: What browser are you using? What is the content of your answer?

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I'm able to answer that question perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883836/read-actionscript-3-constants-from-swf-in-php/7884005#7884005) (Deleted so 10-Kers only) so it must be something you're doing specifically...

- What browser are you using?
- What is the content of your answer?
- Can you answer other questions?
- Does clearing cache and/or cookies help?

Comment: I didn't do anything differently or clear my cache etc but it's letting me post since you did a dummy answer. *shudder*

Comment: I have that effect sometimes. Probably due to my display name ;-)

Comment: Hahah. Will accept this answer once the time limit has expired, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

We had a bit of a glitch with the server you were on.  It was temporary and has since been fixed, so all should be well now!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this response - clears my mind of possible browser issues :P

Comment: Oh come on, "Josh magically fixed it" is *such* a better answer!!! ;-)